# How to enable side loading feature using csom

Tags: sharepoint-addin

How to enable side loading feature using csom. please post solution.

Comment: why you are not going with PowerShell script?

Comment: yeah i know...however i want to enable it using csom.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this while writing a JS in app.js in SharePoint Hosted App on very first line so that the first thing it will activate the side loading feature as this feature does not have any button by which we can activate. So we need to go with the Feature GUID.

Please go through the given article [Enable Side Loading Feature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2013/10/05/enabling-the-developer-site-collection-feature-in-sharepoint-online/)

Please let me know whether it helped you.

Thanks